# Get color behind an object

Tags: ios, swift, colors, uibutton

I want to invert a button that looks like the following:

[image: button to be inverted]

Inverting, in this case, would mean making the title blue and the button's background white. Since I do not want to hard-code it, I cannot simply set it blue. When I set the background color to white, and the title's color to `clearColor`, of course, the title is not readable anymore:

[image: button inverted incorrectly]

Is there a way to find out the color that is behind the button (which is a background image of the view currently), so I can set the title's color to that color?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Following on from [Kjuly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35377980/2976878), you should create a `UIButton` subclass to do this.**

In order to apply your different styles, you just want to add some action listeners for the button touch events in order to re-draw your button when the state changes.

As Kjuly says, you'll then want to override `drawRect` in order to do your custom button drawing, depending on whether the button is pressed or not.

Something like this should achieve what you're after.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    private let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    private var titleAttributes = [String:AnyObject]()
    private var isPressed = false

    var highlightColor = UIColor.whiteColor() { // stroke & highlight color of the button
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    var cornerRadius:CGFloat = 10.0 { // corner radius of button
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    var strokeWidth:CGFloat = 5.0 { // stroke width of button
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonWasPressed"), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonWasReleased"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonWasReleased"), forControlEvents: .TouchDragExit)
        addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonWasReleased"), forControlEvents: .TouchCancel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func buttonWasPressed() {
        isPressed = true
        setNeedsDisplay() // set button to be redrawn
    }

    func buttonWasReleased() {
        isPressed = false
        setNeedsDisplay() // set button to be redrawn
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let size = bounds.size
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        if isPressed { // button pressed down

            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius) // path of button shape for filling

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, highlightColor.CGColor) // white background of the button
            path.fill() // fill path

            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .DestinationOut) // set blend mode for transparent label

        } else { // button not pressed

            let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, UIEdgeInsets(top: strokeWidth*0.5, left: strokeWidth*0.5, bottom: strokeWidth*0.5, right: strokeWidth*0.5)), cornerRadius: cornerRadius-strokeWidth*0.5) // path of button shape for stroking

            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, highlightColor.CGColor) // set stroke color
            path.lineWidth = strokeWidth
            path.stroke()
        }

        guard let label = titleLabel else {return} // title label
        guard let text = label.text else {return} // text to draw

        // update text attributes, add any extra attributes you want transferred here.
        paragraphStyle.alignment = label.textAlignment
        titleAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = label.font
        titleAttributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] = paragraphStyle
        titleAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = label.textColor

        let textHeight = text.sizeWithAttributes(titleAttributes).height // heigh of the text to render, with the attributes
        let renderRect = CGRect(x:0, y:(size.height-textHeight)*0.5, width:size.width, height:size.height) // rect to draw the text in

        text.drawInRect(renderRect, withAttributes: titleAttributes) // draw text
    }
}
```

You can then use this button by setting the various attributes on the button's `titleLabel`, as well the `strokeWidth` and `cornerRadius` property. For example:

```
let button = CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 75))

button.titleLabel?.text = "Let's go!"
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30)
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

button.cornerRadius = 15.0
button.strokeWidth = 5.0
view.addSubview(button)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a subclass of the UIButton (or just UIControl), and override the `-drawRect:` to do rending w/ custom blend mode (`kCGBlendModeDestinationOut`):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill]; // white background of the button
  UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:5.f];
  [path fill];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSaveGState(context);
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut); // Set blend mode

  // u'd better to cache this attributes if u need to redraw the button frequently.
  NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
  paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.f], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};
  [@"Let's Go" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.f, 0.f) withAttributes:attributes];
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

The `kCGBlendModeDestinationOut` is the blend mode you need to set, which will just show the view below current one (R = D*(1 - Sa)), in your case, the background image.

And about blend mode:

> ... R, S, and D are, respectively,
>          premultiplied result, source, and destination colors with alpha; Ra,
>          Sa, and Da are the alpha components of these colors.
>
> The Porter-Duff "source over" mode is called `kCGBlendModeNormal':
>            R = S + D*(1 - Sa)
>
> Note that the Porter-Duff "XOR" mode is only titularly related to the
>          classical bitmap XOR operation (which is unsupported by
>          CoreGraphics).

Comment: sorry, just notice ur swift tag, i think u can convert it to swift version easily, right? ;)

Comment: I had nothing better to do this morning, so [I did a quick Swift port](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35379187/2976878).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It appears to work, but I can somehow not place it in another method than the `drawRect()`, can I? B/c it complains about `CGContextSetBlendMode` & `CGContextRestoreGState`: "invalid context 0x0". Any idea?

Comment: @LinusG. as far as i know, u can only do such drawing in `-drawRect()` method, that's why i asked u to offer a custom class that subclass from UIControl or UIButton for ur button. :)

Comment: Ok cool, but I want to switch between the states of the button. When pressed it should be inverted (w/ white bg) and when released in normal state (bg w/ color of behind the button).

Comment: @LinusG. I have updated my answer showing how you could do this

Answer (score 0):

If your `UIButton` sits in a `UIView` and You want to access the `UIView's` backgroundColor, you can do so my referencing the `UIButton's` superclass.

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myButton.backgroundColor = myButton.superview?.backgroundColor
}
```

If you want to use the color of a Background Image you might want to have a look into CoreImage to get the average or perPixel Color of that image.

Comment: Unfortunately its not that simple since the background image is not just one-colored. The color behind the button depends on where it is. I'll check out the libraries, thanks for the suggestion